# Should I process Slang/Bad words masking on Server side (or Client side) to achieve better performance?

Tags: mysql, node.js, redis, server, client

I have been developing a real time chatting service and need to mask bad words which client sends. So, now I am wondering about system performance as thousands of msgs transfer at a real time.

***Which part (server or client) process is the best solution masking bad words to get better performance?***

Client side : Android

Server side : Nodejs (MySQL, Redis)

Methods I am thinking :

- Download slang list from server and when client sends a msg (if bad word) mask it. Process can take long time but there may be good search algorithm.
- Put slang list on redis and on every msg server processing check for bad word (through redis query) and send masked msg to client and endpoint. Through redis sounds great but I have to send back masked msg to client, this seems me making the system slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the masked message realtime then implement it on both end. Client side would take care of displaying the message and simultaneously send it to server (async process) for masking and saving to database.

Make sure that the algorithms for masking are same at both end so that the data displayed realtime and one which will be pulled from database will be same.